# Why does "position: relative" interfere with "transform: scale"?

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-transforms

Given the following markup and style

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
label {
  /*position: relative;*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>some random text</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>some random text</label>
</div>
```

when hovering over the first `div` some letter from the second `div` are being "hidden" under the scaled element. When, however, `position: relative` is set on the `label` element, the text gets rendered over the scaled element:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
label {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>some random text</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>some random text</label>
</div>
```

I'm trying to understand the reasoning behind this. Since this seams consistent across browsers, I'm thinking that it is defined in the specs. If so, what's the rationale? And how do I "turn it off", if can't touch the relative positioning?

Comment: Eh... it's not really interfering.  What you're seeing is a z-index stacking issue.  Your `label`s have a position other than static which implicitly changes the rendering to be "on top" of other elements including the containing `div`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying a transform to an element causes it to establish a new stacking context.

Positioning an element (i.e. setting its `position` to something other than `static`) doesn't necessarily cause it to establish a stacking context, in particular a relatively positioned element with `z-index: auto` (the default) does not establish a stacking context.

That being said, both types of elements are grouped together in the painting order defined in [section 9.9 of CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#layers):

> Within each stacking context, the following layers are painted in back-to-front order:
>
> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
> 4. the non-positioned floats.
> 5. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 6. **the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.**
> 7. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

When you hover the first `div`, it becomes a child stacking context with stack level 0, but this child stacking context participates in the same parent stacking context as the `label` in the second `div` as the second `div` itself doesn't establish a stacking context.

As all of your elements have the same stack level of 0 (based on the default `z-index: auto`), the spec says:

> Boxes with the same stack level in a stacking context are stacked back-to-front according to document tree order.

Since your first `div` occurs before the second `div` and *its* `label`, the `label` of the second `div` is painted over the first `div` despite the transform.

You can fix this by specifying `z-index: 1` on `div:hover`:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px 5px;
}
div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
label {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>some random text</label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>some random text</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoohoo! You go, BoltClock! Nice answer.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle: Aw you make me blush - considering you even deleted your +2 answer!

Comment: It wasn't nearly as well researched as yours.  I'll probably bookmark this for when I need to find the stacking level on W3C.  I swear that site makes it entirely too dificult to find anything.

Comment: @Joseph Marikle: Funnily enough, I actually have a [handful of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A106224+%22within+each+stacking+context%22) that all point to the same list. And none of the questions I answered are duplicates of one another.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. I've learned some interesting things from it. I'm just going to say that you probably didn't test it in Chrome/Opera. I've actually tried setting the `z-index` before posting the question, but without luck. If I would have also tested it in Firefox or even Internet Explorer, I could have seen that the results are different.

Comment: @BoltClock I have a similar html ... but the problem is that 'position: relative' is causing text blurry..if I remove the 'position relative' the text becomes clear.. the text blurry disappears..