# Using CSS Scale/Matrix doesn't keep background aligned with elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have a div with a dotted background. There are some child elements. If I apply the following CSS:

```
transform:scale(x);
```

then the elements no longer align with the background, even if that scale is set to 1 (i've also tried with this transform:matrix(...)).

I've made a fiddle to demonstrate what I mean:
https://jsfiddle.net/gawdhfpc/

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: blue;
}
.toTransform {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(black 3px, white 3px);
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  /* comment to see what it should look like */
  transform: scale(1);
}
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 258px;
  left: 258px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="toTransform">
    <div class="child">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you remove the transform css, you'll see that the child lines up with the dots on the background. Once the transform applies, the child gets shifted and is no longer aligned with the dots. Why is this happening? Is there some way to fix this? I need to let the user zoom in/out, and i've been doing this with D3 and scale/translate.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, but I don't actually know what is causing the underlying problem.

Your red square child has `position:absolute`, but it has no parents with `position:relative`, so it is being positioned absolutely relative to the document itself. When you apply a transform, for whatever reason it then gets positioned absolutely relative to .toTransform, which in your example is ~10 px offset from the document, due to natural margin and padding. Essentially, by adding the transform *it appears to be acting as though you have implicitly applied `position:relative` to `.toTransform`*.

So, if you do that initially, adding/removing the transform should not interfere, IE,

```
.toTransform {
  position:relative;
}
.child {
  /* drop each value by ~10px */
  top: 248px;
  left: 248px;
}
```

And now the position of the square should be unaffected whether or not you have the transform.

Possibly related:[Why does "position: relative" interfere with "transform: scale"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461007/why-does-position-relative-interfere-with-transform-scale)