# Why does `transform: scale(1)` change footer position (in Chrome)?

Tags: html, css, transform

I am investigating why `transform: scale(2)` changes my footer position, and interestingly, I can reproduce something similar with `transform: scale(1)`. So I am comparing these two documents, which I would expect to appear identical:

```html
<body style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; transform-origin:top left; transform:none">
  <footer style="position:fixed; bottom:0">I'm down here!</footer>
</body>
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #000000; color: #ffffff; transform-origin:top left; transform:scale(1)">
  <footer style="position:fixed; bottom:0">I'm down here!</footer>
</body>
```

However, the footer position is different between the two - note the (visual) distance to the bottom, while the computed `bottom` is the same:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the duplicate deals with filter but it's a generic duplicate detailing at the end all the properties that have the same effect (including transform)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35461412/4218046

Comment: @FabianS. that's not the same issue. That one doesn't involve position:fixed

Comment: _"Positioning an element (i.e. setting its position to something other than static)"_. `fixed` is something other than `static`, so it actually similar is and describe whats happening. I personally encountered exactly this issue and that answer helped me understand what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. For anyone else wondering, in this simple example one can add `<body style="height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; ...` to both variants and the positioning is the same in both variants (even though a bit different from the original one).